# Maximize profit with given demand probability

Tags: statistics, optimization, random-variables, statistical-inference

> **Problem** A grocer stock pear. On any given day, demand for one, two or three pears is 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, respectively. He buys the fruits at 60 cents each and sells them at one dollar each. Left overs will be thrown away by the end of the day. How many pears should the grocer purchase to maximize his daily profit?

I think I should obtain an expression for the mean profit in terms of number of fruits stocked, let's say n.

The profit function in general is given by
$$ p(q)q-C(q) \text{ or, less often as } q(p)p-C(p)$$
Daily profit will be a random variable: Y=100-60=40X

Therefore: 
$$E[Y]=40\sum_{k=0}^{n}kP(X=k)=40\left(0\cdot0.2+1\cdot0.5+2\cdot0.3...\right)$$

This is what have so far, and I do not know how to continue from there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that he should stock at least $1$ pear and at most $3$ pears.

Let $n$ be the number of pears stocked.

Take cases, based on the value of $n$.

If $n=1$, he sells $1$, hence the profit is

$$(1)(1) - (1)(.6) = .4$$

If $n=2$, the expected number sold is

$$(.2)(1) + (.8)(2) = 1.8$$

hence the expected profit is

$$(1.8)(1) - (2)(.6) = .6$$

If $n=3$, the expected number sold is

$$(.2)(1) + (.5)(2) + (.3)(3) = 2.1$$

hence the expected profit is

$$(2.1)(1) - (3)(.6) = .3$$

Since the expected profit is maximized for $n=2$, he should stock $2$ pears.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm just a little confused on why we start adding demand expectation starting at n=2, why not start from n=1? I know it doesn't make much sense to have a none integer number for when n=1.... Sorry I'm still in the learning process.

Comment: If $n=1$, what is the probability that  the one stocked pear will be sold?

Comment: that would be equal to the demand probability, which is 0.2? Or is it 100% that is at 1?

Comment: It's 100%. Why?

Comment: they have no other choice but to take the only option ?

Comment: Right. The assumption of the model is if they want $2$, they'll still take $1$ if that's all there is.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!

Comment: But note, that's just an assumption of the model. In the real world, someone who wants $2$ and only sees one might decide to buy none and instead try another store.

Comment: true, but this condition maybe out of scope for this type of question? More information will have to be added to assume the special circumstance?

Comment: Right -- just assume that a person will take any amount up to their demand.

Comment: My answer is right, but my comments could use a minor revision. To say that the probability of selling $2$ pears is $.5$ doesn't imply that with probability $.5$, some customer would buy $2$. It's the set of customers as a whole that would buy $2$. Thus, on a day when $2$ pears are sold, it means either two customers each bought $1$, or one customer bought $2$. From the point of view of the grocer, it doesn't matter which. But as we previously discussed, if only one pear is stocked, it will be sold with probability $.2+.5+.3=1$.